# Find the probability with a geometric random variable for when X is greater than some value.

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables

I encountered this problem, and upon solving it incorrectly, I was given the following solution, however I don't understand the logic behind the solution:

Consider a geometric random variable, X, with PMF $p(1-p)^{x-1}$ for $ x = 1, 2, ...$

What is the $P(X > 5)$?

The solution is as follows:

(1) $P(X > 5) = P(X \geq{6})$

(2) $\Sigma_{x=6}^{\infty}p(1-p)^{(x-1)}$

(3) $(1-p)^{5} \Sigma_{x=6}^{\infty} p(1-p)^{(x-5-1)}$

(4) $(1-p)^{5} \Sigma_{x=1}^{\infty} p(1-p)^{x-1}$

(5) $ = (1-p)^{5}$

I am having difficulty understanding how we get from step 3 to step 4.  That is, how do we justify changing the summation from being on the range of 6 to infinity to 1 to infinity?  And how do we justify changing the exponent from $x-5-1$ to $x-1$?

Comment: It's just re-indexing the summation; write out the terms of the sums in 3 and 4 to see they are the same

Comment: You're absolutely right, the summations are effectively the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An alternative solution is to note that $X>5$ iff the first $5$ trials are failures which by independence is given by
$$
P(X>5) = (1-p)^5.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $y=x-5$. Then the summation becomes $$\sum_{x=6}^\infty p(1-p)^{x-5-1}=\sum_{y=1}^\infty p(1-p)^{y-1}.$$ But $x$ and $y$ are both dummy variables, so we can now relabel $y\to x$ without changing the value of the sum. Since $y$ immediately disappears, it's common to elide this step and say that we've shifted $x\mapsto x+5$ while changing the limits accordingly.